# How to find out the security token in the org?

Tags: security-token

How to find out the security token in the org?

I tried to go to Settings, but I do not see the option there.

[image]

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glADAAY Refer this link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check in your profile level,Any "IP restriction" applied for your profile.In that case also it will not show security token to you

***Usually we will find security Token like this:***

> Yourname→ My Settings → Personal → Reset Security Token

***Please check these Links:***

1. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000grjhAAA
2. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glADAAY